# Cannot launch Nsight Compute command-line interface on Windows

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, nvidia, nsight-compute

I cannot launch NVIDIA's Nsight CLI with the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightComputeCli/index.html) and after installing Nsight Compute v1.0.

I took a look at the batch file `nv-nsight-cu-cli.bat` and all it does is launch `nv-nsight-cu-cli.exe`. However, I took a look in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA Nsight Compute 1.0\host\windows-desktop-win7-wgl-x64` where the batch file says the CLI executable resides but it's missing. There is only an executable to launch the UI.

Where can I download `nv-nsight-cu-cli.exe` and get Nsight CLI to work? I cannot find it from the NVIDIA website.

Comment: The .bat file appears to be pointing at the incorrect location. The file is located in the target directory. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA Nsight Compute 1.0\target\windows-desktop-win7-wgl-x64.

Comment: The last directory name is changing from windows-desktop-win7-wgl-x64 to windows-desktop-win7-x64 (drops wgl).